Get-AzAccessToken tries to authenticate using federated credentials (OIDC token), despite having signed in using azure/login and enable-AzPSSession
I sign-in with Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell module using azure/login@v2 with enable-AzPSSession: true.
It works, and I'm able to deploy infrastructure using Bicep.
However, the Grant-ServiceAccess.ps1 script fails in the following call:
Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph -AsSecureString

The error says that the client assertion is not valid, as it has expired. It's only valid for 5 minutes, like it's the case for GitHub Actions OIDC token:
https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/441
Why does Get-AzAccessToken try to sign-in again, when I have already signed-in using the Azure Powershell module, and why does it try to sign-in using the GitHub OIDC token?
How can I use the current authenticated Aure PowerShell module session to request a token for MS Graph?
Error:
Get-AzAccessToken: /home/runner/work/X/Y/infra/scripts/Grant-ServiceAccess.ps1:15
Line |
  15 |  … ccessToken (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph -AsSecureStri …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | ClientAssertionCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue
     | is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server
     | for details. You can modify the configuration in the application
     | registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for
     | details.  Original exception: AADSTS700024: Client assertion is not
     | within its valid time range. Current time: 2024-11-25T12:29:03.7085596Z,
     | assertion valid from 2024-11-25T12:14:19.0000000Z, expiry time of
     | assertion 2024-11-25T12:19:19.0000000Z. Review the documentation at
     | https://learn.microsoft.com/entra/identity-platform/certificate-credentials . Trace ID: 94218eb9-8060-4a83-81a3-6d1dfac32d00 Correlation ID: f7f38824-7ca7-4c40-a39c-3bfe12944db4 Timestamp: 2024-11-25 12:29:03Z

GitHub Actions:
  deploy-infra:
    name: Deploy infrastructure
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    needs: validate-infra
    outputs:
      functionAppId: ${{ steps.deploy-output.outputs.functionAppId }}
      functionAppName: ${{ steps.deploy-output.outputs.functionAppName }}
      functionAppUrl: ${{ steps.deploy-output.outputs.functionAppUrl }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ vars.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
          enable-AzPSSession: true
      - name: Deploy infrastructure
        uses: azure/cli@v2
        with:
          azcliversion: ${{ vars.AZURE_CLI_VERSION }}
          inlineScript: |
            az stack sub create  \
              --name ${{ inputs.deploymentStackName }} \
              --location ${{ inputs.location }} \
              --action-on-unmanage deleteAll \
              --deny-settings-mode denyDelete \
              --template-file ./infra/main.bicep \
              --parameters environment=${{ inputs.environment }} \
                resourceGroupName=${{ inputs.deploymentStackName }} \
                aclGroupId=${{ vars.ACL_GROUP_ID }} \
              --yes
      - name: Deployment outputs
        id: deploy-output
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
          Install-Module -Name Az.Resources
          (Get-AzSubscriptionDeploymentStack -Name ${{ env.deploymentStackName }}).Outputs.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value.Value)" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT }
        env:
          deploymentStackName: ${{ inputs.deploymentStackName }}
      - name: Grant access to managed identity
        if: inputs.environment == 'dev'
        shell: pwsh
        run: ./infra/scripts/Grant-ServiceAccess.ps1 -ServicePrincipalId ${{ env.userAssignedIdentityId }} -AclGroupId ${{ env.aclGroupId }}
        env:
          aclGroupId: ${{ vars.ACL_GROUP_ID }}
          userAssignedIdentityId: ${{ steps.deploy-output.outputs.userAssignedIdentityId }}

Grant-ServiceAccess.ps1:
param (
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$ServicePrincipalId,
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$AclGroupId
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true

Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts, Microsoft.Graph 

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph -AsSecureString).Token -NoWelcome


Are you still facing the issue. @Shuzheng

@Jahnavi - Yes, I am :)

@Jahnavi - I don't understand why Azure PowerShell attempts to use the GitHub Actions OIDC token, when I already signed in using azure/login@v2. If I sign-in using az login locally, then I get use that session to get tokens, like az account get-access-token ...

Get-AzAccessToken works independently of the active Azure PowerShell session and does not reuse the session token obtained via Connect-AzAccount. The Get-AzAccessToken solely works for the token retrieval part. @Shuzheng

@Jahnavi Thank for clarifying. azure/login@v2 calls Connect-AzAccount, right? But why doesn't Get-AzAccessToken works with the existing Azure PowerShell session, when az account get-access-token works with the existing Azure CLI session? Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this workflow, i.e. use the existing Azure PowerShell session with Get-AzAccessToken? Calling azure/login@v2 again doesn't fix it, as the GitHub OIDC token is job-based. I could move the Grant access to managed identity step to its own job, but I would prefer not

To make it work without moving to Grant access to managed identity, I would suggest you to explicitly reconnect to Azure with Connect-AzAccount in the script where you call Grant-ServiceAccess.ps1. By reconnecting, you ensure Get-AzAccessToken uses the correct session instead of falling back to the expired OIDC token. @Shuzheng

If that is ok with you, I can provide you the modified script approach. @Shuzheng

@Jahnavi Thank you for offering this. I would like that! Looking forward to see your solution

So, Connect-AzAccount will use the existing Azure PowerShell module session created by azure/login@v2, while Get-AzAccessToken will attempt to create a new session using the GitHub Actions OIDC token? That's odd. What's specifically meant by Azure PowerShell module? Isn't it the Az family of cmdlets?

Yes right. Both commands belong to the same Az family cmdlets. Connect-AzAccount is an Az PowerShell command which initializes an Azure session for the PowerShell module, typically depends on an authentication mechanism provided at runtime. (Eg: GitHub actions) whereas Get-AzAccesstoken is also an Az PowerShell command that retrieves an access token for a specified resource here it is MSGraph.  It initiates its own authentication flow rather than reusing the authenticated login session. @Shuzheng

Basically, Get-AzAccessToken works independently of the active Azure PowerShell session and does not reuse the session token obtained via Connect-AzAccount.
To be continued from the comments, both commands belong to the Az PowerShell family cmdlets which I already mentioned.
Get-AzAccesstoken is an Az PowerShell module command that retrieves an access token for a specified resource here it is (MSGraph). It does not prefer to reuse the authenticated login session by Connect-AzAccount PowerShell session.
Modified PS script has given below:
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).Token
$Secure_Token = ConvertTo-SecureString $accessToken -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $Secure_Token -NoWelcome

Complete PowerShell code:
param (
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$ServicePrincipalId,
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$AclGroupId
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference = $true
Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts, Microsoft.Graph
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).Token
$Secure_Token = ConvertTo-SecureString $accessToken -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $Secure_Token -NoWelcome




Thank you. What's specifically meant by Azure PowerShell module? It's the Az module, right? https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/13.0.0

Do you know why we observe this difference in behaviour between Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell module: az account get-access-token use the authenticated session established by az login, but Get-AzAccessToken doesn't use the authenticated session established by Connect-AzAccount?

I think that the Modified PS script has given below section should be removed, as it doesn't really introduce anything new. The gist of your code is Connect-AzAccount -Identity. Could you elaborate on that?

Regarding Connect-AzAccount -Identity, in my case, I'm not using a managed identity, but is connecting to Azure by means of OIDC federated credentials on a service principal

Is the issue solved for you. @Shuzheng
